# existence of Borel measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

Can we find a Borel measurable function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow (0,\infty)$ such that $\int \mathcal{X}_I f d\mu = \infty$  for every nonempty open interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$, where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ ?

I think the answer is true; there is such a function, but with this condition "integral = infinity" this makes $f$ is unbounded almost everywhere, so not sure how to define it, if it exists.

Comment: @user10354138 not sure! if $f(x)=1/x$ or $\sqrt{x}$ then $\int \mathcal{X}_I f $ won't be $\infty$ for any open interval $I$, right?

Comment: See [zhw's answer](/a/1731594) there.  The function $F^2+1$ is an example of what you are looking for.

Comment: you are right! thanks